# Does using pseudo elements like :first-child or :last-child

Tags: html, css, dom, browser, rendering

I firstly say that i don't know anything about how css rules are assigned to DOM elements by browser, so that my question is more around it, but i got wondering this in this particular situation I got into, so I use it for formalizing my curiosity:

I do have an HTML snippet like this:

```
<section>
 <div>I'd like to be blue</div>
 <div style="color:green">I am quite <p style="font-weight: bold">self confident</p> about my styles</div>
 <p>I'd like to be biig</p>
</section>
```

The text's content of the `div`s tries to describe my requirements: The first `div` MUST be blue, the second one i don't care because I will probably use inherited properties or I will set through js or whatever. 
The `p` should be bold,

So I want to assign styles to do that, and I do something like this:

```
section div {
 color: blue;
}

section p {
 font-weight: bold;
}
```

And that obviously works as expected. But, CSS has nice features to target more specific elements. So I could do, for doing the same thing:

```
section > div:first-child {
 color: blue;
}

section > p {
 font-weight: bold;
}
```

This will affect only elements that are direct children of the section, and only the first div of the set, so that i will have the same result, but selecting elements more specifically. 
I wonder if this helps browsers assigning css rules to elements. 
I think that at some level the browser check for each DOM element the css' rules that target it, and if it finds matches (a css class is actually targeting it), it checks for conflicts and performs overriding if needed.

Would excluding elements from that sets, by targeting them more specifically help the browser to assign style (increase performance or decrease) ?

If it increases, is it meaningful or it is so little that everyone ignores it ?

If it decreases, how much and why ?

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: The whole purpose of CSS selectors is to target specific elements. A more specific selector overrides other rules with less-specific selectors. The `first-child` selector is just another selector to narrow down the target group of elements.

Comment: I understood this, but does it affect performance of browser (when it assign style to dom elements) ? @JacobGray

Comment: this article (and the presentation linked at the bottom of it) may be of interest to you, though it is a couple years old http://calendar.perfplanet.com/2011/css-selector-performance-has-changed-for-the-better/

Comment: @MrLister OP posted two examples and wants to know which is more performant and why. I see no problem here.

Comment: Performance is the worst possible reason for choosing one selector over another. Choose your selectors to target the set of elements to which you want the styles to apply, in terms of elements that exist on your page and likely future enhancements to that page, by considering the semantics of the content.

Answer (score 2):

According to [this article from Mozilla Development Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Writing_efficient_CSS), the more specific your selectors are, the better. So if you do not bother how many divs get colored blue, the general selector section div is better. The longer your selector chain is, the harder it is for the browser to find that element since it needs to match more things. The most performant option in this case would actually assigning a class named for example `.blue` to the div you want blue.

The `element>element` (direct child) selector is [more performant](http://csswizardry.com/2011/09/writing-efficient-css-selectors/) than the `element element` (descendand) selector in the sandbox but will probably force you to write a longer selector chain if you wish to overwrite it at another point.

To answer your question, in your example (at least in a nutshell), the overall performance will probably decrease by a little (meaningless) bit since pseudo-elements like :first-child are the least performant selectors and you furtherly have a longer selector chain.

If you actually asked me which of those to use in a project with more than just six lines of css, I'd encourage you to use the first example aswell since it's much more easy to overwrite and reuse.